# Why are these estimates to the German tank problem different?

Tags: statistics

> Suppose that I observe $k=4$ tanks with serial numbers $2,6,7,14$.
>   What is the best estimate for the total number of tanks $n$?

I assume the observations are drawn from a discrete uniform distribution with the interval $[1,n]$. I know that for a $[0,1]$ interval the expected maximum draw $m$ for $k$ draws is  $1 - (1/(1+k))$. So I estimate $\frac {k}{k+1}$$(n-1)≈$ $m$, rearranged so $n≈$ $\frac {k+1
}{k}$$m+1$.

But the frequentist estimate from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_tank_problem) is defined as:

$n ≈ m-1 + $$\frac {m}{k}$

I suspect there is some flaw in the way I have extrapolated from one interval to another, but I would welcome an explanation of why I have gone wrong!

Comment: You seem to have arrived near the frequentist estimate instead of the Bayesian one.

Comment: Just wondering, how do you arrive at $1-\frac{1}{1+k}$?

Comment: the exact expected value of the  maximum serial number given $k$ out of $n$ tanks is $\frac{k}{k+1}(n+1)$. Note when $k=n$ you expect $n$. The continuous cases is the limit of this case.

Comment: I've just tagged that section of the Wikipedia article as questionable, and commented on the discussion page [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:German_tank_problem#.22The.22_frequentist_estimate_and_.22the.22_Bayesian_estimate.3F.3F).

Comment: I suspect that by "frequentist" estimate, whoever wrote that meant "best unbiased estimate".  Not that an MLE would also be a frequentist estimate, but would be different from that.

Answer (score 2):

Just seen what went wrong. I accidentally put in a plus sign instead of a minus sign. Ugh:

$n≈$ $\frac {k+1}{k}$$m+1$ should be $n≈$ $\frac {k+1}{k}$$m-1$.

This is the same as the frequentist formula.

Answer (score 0):

What Thomas mentioned in the comment is correct.

The German Tank Problem is different from drawing random samples from a uniform distribution, in which case the expected sample maximum is $\frac{k}{k+1}(n-1)+1$. (maximum of k samples in $U(1, n)$)

Instead, we are sampling without replacement - we can never obtain two tank samples with the same serial number.