# German tank problem, simple derivation

Tags: probability, binomial-coefficients, factorial

I was reading the [recent question on the German tank problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/455840/why-are-these-estimates-to-the-german-tank-problem-different), and had trouble with one of the derivations in [this section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_tank_problem#Derivation).

> $$\sum_{m=k}^N m \frac{\binom{m-1}{k-1}}{\binom N k} = \frac{k(N+1)}{k+1}$$

I understand where the left-hand side comes from, in the context of the problem. I'm just having trouble arriving at the right-hand side.

\begin{align*}
\sum_{m=k}^N m \frac{\binom{m-1}{k-1}}{\binom N k} &= \sum_{m=k}^N m \frac{(m-1)!}{(k-1)!(m-k)!} \frac{k! (N-k)!}{N!}\\
&= k \sum_{m=k}^N \frac{m!}{(m-k)!} \frac{(N-k)!}{N!}
\end{align*}

This looks promising, since I have found the $k$ that appears in the right-hand side, but I don't know what to do with the sum.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a binomial identity that $\displaystyle \sum_{m=k}^N \binom{m}{k} = \binom{N+1}{k+1}$,

You can see this by induction on $N$, if $N = k$, $\binom{k}{k} = \binom{k+1}{k+1}$, and if it is true that 
$$\displaystyle \sum_{m=k}^N \binom{m}{k} = \binom{N+1}{k+1}$$
then 
$$\displaystyle \sum_{m=k}^{N+1} \binom{m}{k} = \binom{N+1}{k+1} + \binom{N+1}{k} = \binom{N+2}{k+1}$$.

Now your sum was 
$$k \displaystyle \sum_{m=k}^N \frac{m!}{(m-k)!} \frac{(N-k)!}{N!} 
= \frac{k!k(N-k)!}{N!} \displaystyle \sum_{m=k}^N \binom{m}{k} 
= \frac{k(N-k)!k!}{N!} \binom{N+1}{k+1} 
= \frac{k(N+1)}{k+1}$$

Comment: Beat me by about a minute...

Comment: I think that $k!$ should be in the numerator, but other than that it looks good. Thanks!

Comment: Fixed the $k!$.

Answer (score 2):

$$\sum_{m=k}^N m\frac{{m-1 \choose k-1}}{{N \choose k}}=\frac{1}{{N\choose k}}\sum_{m=k}^N m{m-1 \choose k-1}=\frac{1}{{N\choose k}}\sum_{m=k}^{N}k{m \choose k}$$
The last step uses an [identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Identities_involving_binomial_coefficients).

Now this equals $$\frac{k}{{N\choose k}}\sum_{m=k}^{N} {m \choose k}=\frac{k}{{N\choose k}}\sum_{m=0}^{N} {m \choose k} =\frac{k}{{N\choose k}}{N+1\choose k+1}$$

Comment: Looks like I am unfamiliar with a lot of identities on that page... thanks for the answer and the resource!